# Ouput ping status on django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model that contains domain names which I need to ping. I was able to create the view but I couldn't figure out how to output it on the template.

```
def index(request, page):
  template = "home.html"
  if request.method == 'POST':
      csv_file = request.FILES['file']
      if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
          messages.error(request, 'Please upload a .csv file.')

      data_set = csv_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
      io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
      next(io_string)
      for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
          _, created = Table.objects.update_or_create(
              page=column[0],
              keyword=column[1],
              interval=column[2],
              email=column[3],
              notes=column[4],
              billing=column[5],
          )
  page_object = get_object_or_404(Table, page=page)
  try:
      subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1', page_object.page])
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
      host_online = False
  else:
      host_online = True
  context = {
      'tables': Table.objects.all(),
      'online': host_online,
      'page': page
  }
  return render(request, template, context)
```

the model

```
class Table(models.Model):
  page = models.URLField(verbose_name=None)
```

and this is how I call it on the template

```
{% if online %}
  <i class="small material-icons green-text">check_circle</i>
{% else %}
  <i class="small material-icons red-text">close</i>
{% endif %}
```

Can anyone guide me? 
It's returning `data_upload() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page'`

Comment: You did not pass your `context` to the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just did but when I looped through it, the table was gone.

Comment: So what is `t` there?

Comment: came from the iteration on the model

Answer (score 2):

You've got several problems in your code making it incorrect:

- `domain = Table.objects.filter(page)` will fail. You should do `domain = Table.objects.filter(page=page)`
- You are not actually pinging a domain as `domain` is just a string in your code `subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1',  "domain"])`
- You are not using a context: if you want to access it in the template, you need to pass it to the `render` call:
  `return render(request, 'home.html', context`)

Even more, Django's [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter) function returns a `queryset` object, not a single entity.

My suggestion is to fix your code as follows:

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def pingDomain(request, page):
  page_object = get_object_or_404(Table, page=page)
  try:
      subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1',  page_object.page])
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
      host_online = False
  else:
      host_online = True
  context = {
      'online': host_online
  }
  return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

And then in your template you can simply access it via `online` key:

```
{{online}}
```

Comment: There's no output on the template. I also iterated {% for o in online %} {{o.online}} {% endfor %} but still did not print any code on the template.

Comment: Because `online` is not iterable, you can't iterate over it. It is just a status of one single page

Comment: I currently have 6 items on the page for model. and even if I don't iterate on it, it won't show any output.

Comment: What is a `page` in your code? Does it stand for `domain` (web page) or for page of objects? Provide an example of your page argument

Comment: the page is the URL.

Comment: here's the template https://highcenburg.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Screen+Shot+2019-10-06+at+11.59.46+PM.png

Comment: You can try a little bit more complex template, but it must output something. If not, there's probably another problem in your project.

```context = { 'online': host_online, "page": page}```

And in the template:
```The page {{page}} is {% if online %}online{% else %} offline{%endif%}```

Comment: In your template you've got a list of domains. But the discussed view simply handles exactly one domain at a time. How do you request this view from the template? It seems to me that the view that renders that list and the view to ping the page are **different** views. If so you should ping the domains in the very same view that renders the list

Comment: I updated the question. It's returning ```data_upload() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page'```

Comment: Where that `data_upload` function is called? Can't find in the provided code

Comment: changed it to index since it's called in the home.html

Comment: Hold on, even if the view only handles one domain at a time, it should return a True because the domain is live.

Comment: And it certainly does for the domain you've passed to the view. If you need a view that returns a list of `Table` instances with its statuses – you should not pass any `page` param to the view and simply iterate over `Table.objects.all()` inside your view to get its status and pass all the results with the list itself to the template as a context

Comment: No the domain does not output True even if the first domain is live. I would understand if the other domains would return a False since you've mentioned the pingDomain view does not iterate.